# Cakephp Error: An internal error has occurred

Tags: cakephp, internal-server-error

I have some code in cakephp which produces an error.

Here is the PHP Controller:

```
$this->loadModel( 'Vote' ); //Newly added by amit start
$vote=$this->Vote->getVote($id,$uid);
$this->set('vote',$vote);
$voteCount = count($vote);
$this->set('voteCount',$voteCount);

$voteShow = $this->Vote->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('SUM(Vote.score)   AS score','count(id) as countId'),
     'conditions'=>array('Vote.type_id'=>$id),
));
$this->set('voteShow',$voteShow);
```

model:

```
public function getVote($id,$uid) {
    if (empty($conditions))
        $conditions = array('Vote.type' => 'blog',
                            'Vote.type_id' => $id,
                            'Vote.user_id' => $uid);

    $users = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => 'Vote.id desc'
    ));
    return $users;
}
```

That code produces this error:

```
Error : An internal error has occurred
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I enabled debug mode: `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in core.php and it solved my problem.

Comment: Do NOT do this in production, or you could end up writing sensitive date (such as Query) to user when there will be an error, the reason why debug 2 works is because items in the CACHE are not taken in consideration anymore, so it works. Just delete the cache and leave DEBUG to 0 in production VERY IMPORTANT

Answer (score 4):

In my case debug mode was
`Configure::write('debug', 0);` on live server in core.php.

I set it to `Configure::write('debug', 1);` and no error was shown this time.

So I again changed my debug mode to `Configure::write('debug', 0);` because I don't want to show debug error on my live site.

This time no error message shows up.

**So just changing the debug mode once in core.php** get rid of this error in my case.

***If you change your debug mode to 1 and then run those functions which you have changed on local, CakePHP will refresh the cache for all those models which include in those functions. Now you can change back to `Configure::write('debug', 0)`***.

Comment: see my answer above, and you'll understand why it works when you set it to 1 !

Answer (score 4):

Do NOT set `Configure::write('debug',2)` in production, or you could end up writing sensitive data (such as Query) to user when there will be an error, the reason why debug 2 works is because items in the CACHE are not taken in consideration anymore, so it works. Just delete the cache and leave DEBUG to 0 in production VERY IMPORTANT

Cache can be found here: `tmp/cache/`

Then again, do NOT delete the 3 folder you'll find there, just delete their content.